# pthread leaks memory after it finishes

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I know by calling `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` will release resources used by the thread after it finishes but my situation is not that easy.

First of all I want to be able to terminate the child thread from the parent thread, so I wrote something like this: (the dynamically allocated buf is there to show I can't seem to find a way to use `pthread_detach` because I don't know how to wait for the child thread to finish (so I can free buf) if I detach it)

```
bool running = true;
void *foo(void *buf)
{
    while (running)
    {
        // Do something with buf
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *buf = new char[1024];

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, foo, buf);

    string cmd;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> cmd;

        if (!cmd.compare("stop"))
        {
            running = false;
            pthread_join(tid, NULL);
            delete[] buf;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work. But the child thread sometimes finishes before the parent thread ever wants to terminate it. In this case, the parent thread is blocked so

1. How do I inform the parent thread that the child thread has terminated so the parent thread can call `pthread_join`?
2. Is there a way to use `pthread_detach` and still be able to wait for the child thread to finish so I can free buf afterwards (though it seems I can free buf in the child thread in this demo, it's impossible for my real application)?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying for here. `pthread_join` blocks until the thread is done if it's not already done. This could be a problem in `main` if  the thread takes a long time to exit, but you don't have to worry about missing the exit.

Comment: @user4581301 The problem is if I use `pthread_join` then when the child thread finishes it has to tell the parent thread to call `pthread_join`. If instead I use `pthread_detach` I won't be able to wait for the child thread to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How do I inform the parent thread that the child thread has terminated so the parent thread can call pthread_join?

There are all sorts of options.  Here are three reasonably promising ones:

- You could have the child thread set a global flag variable.
- You could have the child thread signal the parent thread with `pthread_kill()`.
- You could set up a pipe that the child writes to when it's done, and have the parent perform a non-blocking read from it to test whether the child is finished.

> 2. Is there a way to use pthread_detach and still be able to wait for the child thread to finish so I can free buf afterwards (though it
>      seems I can free buf in the child thread in this demo, it's impossible
>      for my real application)?

No.  Once a thread is detached it cannot be joined, ever.

You could consider instead having the thread manage its own resources.  Or if the main thread must allocate resources then at least consider handing off responsibility for managing them to the child thread.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I inform the parent thread that the child thread has terminated so the parent thread can call pthread_join?

Have you considered using std::thread?

I think the following code demonstrates that you need do nothing using std::thread.  The sleep_for() are big enough for humans to watch.

```
void pause_thread(int n, std::string lbl)
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(n));
  std::cout << lbl << " pause of " << n << " seconds ended" << std::endl;
}

int t403(void)
{
   std::cout << "Spawning 3 threads...\n" << std::flush;
   std::thread t1 (pause_thread, 6, "t1");
   std::thread t2 (pause_thread, 3, "t2");
   std::thread t3 (pause_thread, 1, "t3");
   std::cout << "Done spawning threads, "
      "Note that they finish out-of-order. \n"
      "Now 'main' thread waits for spawned threads to join:\n" << std::flush;

   t1.join(); std::cout << "join t1  " << std::flush;
   t2.join(); std::cout << "join t2  " << std::flush;
   t3.join(); std::cout << "join t3  " << std::flush;
   std::cout << "completed join \n"
      "note: \n - join sequence is in-order, but finish sequence is out-of-order\n"
      " - inference:  the threads waited for main to join! "<< std::endl;

   return(0);
}
```

---

Update: 6/1/2016

I have reproduced the above scheme using posix thread and join.  It would appear that the main thread needs no notification that a spawned thread has terminated.

Also, from "man pthread_join":

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by 'thread'
>   (parameter 1) to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated,
>   then pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by
>   thread must be joinable.

Perhaps I am missing something about your question.

Perhaps the thread that is issuing the join should not be trying to do anything else during this time.

Consider moving the "anything else" into its own cooperative thread?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to head off in a different direction. The question should not be "How do I signal end of thread so I can release `buf`?" it should be "How should I assign ownership for `buf`, preferably in such a way that the end of the thread does not matter?"

Either `foo` or `main` should release `buf`. So which?

Case 1: `buf` is allocated but unused by `main`

This case includes `buf` allocated and initialized in `main` so long as `main` does not consume `buf` after thread has finished processing. This case is easy. Thread assumes ownership of `buf` and deletes it when thread is finished.

```
void *foo(void *buf)
{
    while (running)
    {
        // Do something with buf
    }
    delete buf;
    return NULL;
}
```

Case 2: `buf` is allocated by `main`, operated on by `foo`, then consumed by `main`.

Obviously `buf` must be alive for `main` to consume it, so `main` should retain ownership and delete `buf` after consuming. But when? This means it must wait for `foo` to finish processing `buf`, and this means either join or a done message. Now we get to John Bollinger's answer.

Case 3: `buf` is allocated in `foo`, operated on by `foo`, and deleted by `foo`.

This has the advantage of no confusion what-so-ever, and if `main` never touches 
`buf`, `main` should be completely hands-off, including allocation. In a perfect world this looks like:

```
void *foo(void * )
{
    char buf[1024];
    while (running)
    {
        // Do something with buf
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The size of the buffer, if known to `main`, but not to `foo`, can be provided to the thread. For example,

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, foo, &bufsize);
```

and

```
void *foo(void * size)
{
    char * buf = new char[*((int*)size)];
    while (running)
    {
        // Do something with buf
    }
    delete buf;
    return NULL;
}
```

but you should prefer

```
void *foo(void * size)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[*((int*)size)]);
    while (running)
    {
        // Do something with buf
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

to avoid the raw pointer.

Just make sure that `bufsize` does not change before `foo` starts.